# LINQ To SQL Dynamically Sorting

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, sorting

I want to pass the sort field and direction dynamically to the LINQ to SQL codes.  But I could not find the way to perform like that because if I could not write 
users.OrderBy(d => **Field**);

Is there any way to pass the dynamic field to sort?  Thanks.

```
private static IQueryable<user> GetUserData(String Field, String Direction)
{
    UserDataContext dc = new UserDataContext();

    var users = from d
                    in dc.users
                orderby Field ascending
                select d;

    if (Direction == "ascending")
    {
        return users.OrderBy(d => d.userName);
    }
    else
    {
        return users.OrderByDescending(d => d.userName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Queryable.OrderBy` extension method takes a parameter of type `Expression<Func<TSource, TKey>>`. This does not have to be created using a lambda expression, but can be constructed by hand via the [Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.aspx) class, which lets you construct any kind of expression dynamically in code. This can be used to create a dynamic OrderBy method.

I also read about the [LINQ Dynamic Query Library](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) in a recent question, which seems to have a method that does exactly that. It's apparently included as a code example in some sample collection for VS2008, read the link for more information.